# React Component Children Testing

Tags: reactjs, integration-testing

I'm trying to test the functionality of a deeply nested component, but am having trouble "selecting" it for a `Simulate`.

The way I've been approaching the problem is with the following:

```js
const component = renderIntoDocument(TestParent);
const dropdown = findRenderedComponentWithType(component, TimespanDropdown);
const buttons = scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(dropdown, 'button');
Simulate.click(buttons[0]);
```

This falls apart when I pass dropdown to `srcyRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag`. I could add a class to my buttons and maybe use `scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass`, but I'd rather see if there's a way to somehow "chain" these util find calls.

Comment: which version of React are you using?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could simplify this series of calls is to use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`  on your root component and then use `querySelector` to go directly to the elements that you care about:

```
const component = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(renderIntoDocument(TestParent));
const buttons = component.querySelector('button');
Simulate.click(buttons[0]);
```